# Recording audio from the front facing mic, on the iphone 5

Tags: microphone, iphone-5

I have an app that takes audio input from the bottom mic to figure out how hard you are blowing, which we then use to play music. We are trying to find a way to be able to use the mic by the camera on the iPhone 5. I can't find any apple documentation for it. Any help would be great.

Comment: It's possible that devs don't get access to all of the device's microphones independently, as the two mics not used to speak into for calls are intended for use with noise cancellation and the like.

Comment: The front facing one on the 5, is used when you are recording video from the front facing camera, so it is used for more than just noise cancellation. I would hope apple would let us access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually discovered that you have to use the rear facing camera, to use the mic on the back. I heard this might be changed in the new release.

Answer (score 0):

There is a technical note by Apple that explains how to select the microphone you want to record audio with: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1799/_index.html